# Form Styling, jqTransform alternatives?

Tags: jquery, css, forms, styling

I use jqTransform and as you can tell by having a look at my recent questions, it's giving me a hard time.

I've seen a few alternatives in the web but I wonder if there's something really worth it? Sometimes I can't tell if the script (or technique) that I found is two months old or two years.

I'm interested in skinning inputs but more importantly, selects (dropdowns).

EDIT: It's not what jqTransform can't do, it's what it won't let me do. I need to reskin my selects, be it with jquery or a css technique or something else without losing the functionality of the selects. With jqTransform I have issues getting the selected values of the selects when you have more than one on the form because they don't have id's after they get reskinned (ofc you can work around that but so far it's only been a headache).

Comment: It's a a vague question, what are your goal? I think for fast coding, you should stay on CSS. If you want something way more interesting you could try flex. Between them there's a lot of solution.

Comment: His goal is pretty clear if you understand what jqTransform is.

Comment: I'm a her, but yeah, I need something to make my selects better. I'm not sure css only solutions are what I need but I would ofc consider them. It's not fast coding, it's a large project I'm working on and I really need my forms to not stand out by their uglyness and be able to unify their looks with the site without losing their capabilities (I can't do a lot of the stuff I need with the selects using jqTransform).

Comment: Be more specific, what do you need to do you can't do with jqTransform. Did you try Jquery UI?

Comment: jqTransform steals a lot of control from the developer. Selects get turned into ul/li and getting at select values is a pain, as an example. I think Elaine wants an alternative that gives you a nice look to forms without the run around. Just guessing here.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, but it seems that you have to give up one of those things, you can't have control and nice looks at the same time it seems due to how browsers render those controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend sticking to CSS if you are merelly looking for a stylistic solution. JavaScript is good to control behaviours and the such, but nothing beats CSS styling forms, both in capabilities and speed.

Some good articles are [Pretty Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms) or [this ones](http://designshack.co.uk/tutorials/10-css-form-examples).

Comment: Those are very nice but they don't style the selects, which are the worse looking of them all...

Comment: "worse looking" is a subjective opinion. If they don't feat in your design scheme then you'll have to use an UI like jQuery UI. Although standardized use of forms in the web is common.